# Separate text and pass it to a SQL

Tags: sql, shell

I'm using the latest Debian version.

I have this file:

```
2301,XT_ARTICLES
2101,XT_HOUSE_PHOTOS
301,XT_PDF
101611,XT_FIJOS
```

I want to separate this text so I can add the ID and the name to a one SQL. The SQL must be repeated according to the number of lines in the file, but I don't know how can I do it.

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: What request to you want with it ? INSERT ?

Comment: is this for mysql? you can use `load data infile` to read what looks to be CSV text.

Comment: what do you mean by "a SQL"?  is it a SQL script, a statement or what?  also, what is your API?  are you just using a shell script that invokes some SQL client or a scripting language?  we need more info

Comment: Sorry, I explained badly. This is for Postgres, I use in mi shell script psql command and is a select. With this selects I'm going to create a txt file. It is a summary of some work I have done previously with a program and I can verify that this statement was made correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Is this fit your needs ?

```
awk -F',' '{print "INSERT INTO foobar VALUES("$1,",\047"$2"\047);"}' file.txt
INSERT INTO foobar VALUES(2301, 'XT_ARTICLES');
INSERT INTO foobar VALUES(2101, 'XT_HOUSE_PHOTOS');
INSERT INTO foobar VALUES(301, 'XT_PDF');
INSERT INTO foobar VALUES(101611, 'XT_FIJOS');
```

If it's ok, just pipe that in MySQL :

```
awk -F',' '
BEGIN{
    print "USE qux;"
}
{
    print "INSERT INTO foobar VALUES("$1,",\047"$2"\047);"
}' file.txt | mysql
```